# Laravel model won't find messages by user id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working on a website with a messages system written in Laravel. To identify a users messages the `messages` table has a `to_user` attribute which - obviously - holds the id of the user to which the message is sent. However, even though there are plenty of sample messages in this table, my `Message` model won't return any results when I search for messages by this attribute.

I've tried several things. First off, `$messages = Message::where('to_user', USER_ID);`, this results in an empty array (except for the standard Eloquent stuff, no actual results from the table). Next, I tried a prettier approach. In my `User` model, I added a fancy relationship like this:

```
/**
 * Get the users messages
 */
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Message', 'to_user');
}
```

Unfortunately though, `$messages = $currentUser->messages()` returns the same empty result as it did on my first try.

Last night when I was having a shower I had an eureka moment (this is definitely essential information needed to solve the problem). I was sure I had the solution, either `$currentUser->id` is a string or the `to_user` attribute must return the `id` as a string for some reason. Unfortunately though, this wasn't the case. `var_dump` shows that both are integers.

Any ideas? I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!
Roemer

Comment: try this `$messages = Message::where('to_user', USER_ID)->get();`

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard one-to-many relationship, the right way to handle this situation is to create the relation in both of your models:

User Model

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Message', 'to_user');
}
```

Message Model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'to_user');
}
```

Then get the messages with:

```
 $messages = User::find(<your_user_id>)->messages()->get()
```

check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) for more info

Comment: You can get messages with this `User::find(<your_user_id>)->messages;` too.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't fetching the results of the query.

`$messages = Message::where('to_user', USER_ID);` This won't return anything

`$messages = Message::where('to_user', USER_ID)->get();` This will return a collection of messages

Answer (score 0):

Your message method returns the `HasMany` class, it is not returning a resultset yet.

Try:

```
$messages = $currentUser->messages()->get();
```

or

```
$messages = Message::where('to_user', USER_ID)->get();
```

I think your problem is you do not finished the query builder.

Answer (score -1):

Did you create a "belongsTo" method in the related class?

Comment: Relationships aren't required to go both ways, so this wouldn't matter.